# Basic AJAX example with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of making a demo ASP.NET MVC app for educational purposes.

I have an image/link that flags a post as offensive.  I would like to request from the server via AJAX to flag offensive and check to make sure that the user has this ability.

If the user does, then I want to flag the post as offensive in the database and return that the flag went through.  If the user ends up NOT having the right to flag items then I would like to return a negative message to the client so I can popup a nice jQuery box stating that it didn't go through.

I'm trying to do this all without a full postback/refresh.

Does anyone have any links to examples of simple AJAX requests being made with MVC?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is actually pretty easy with jQuery. Let's say your link is something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:flagInappropriate(<%=Model.PostId%>);">Flag as inappropriate</a>
```

Create a javascript to call the action in your controller to check and flag as necessary:

```
function flagInappropriate(postId) {
    var url = "<CONTROLLER>/<ACTION>/" + postId;
    $.post(url, function(data) {
        if (data) {
            // callback to show image/flag
        } else {
            // callback to show error/permission
        }
    });
}
```

In you action method in your controller will probably look like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public bool FlagAsInappropriate(int id) {
    // check permission
    bool allow = CheckPermission();

    // if allow then flag post
    if (allow) {
        // flag post

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why in your example code above wouldn't you just return CheckPermission(); ?

Comment: because you may want to do some extra logic/action if CheckPermission returns true - see the // flag post area

Answer (score 0):

Here is using @Ajax object example. More simply it is @Ajax.ActionLink.

http://ovisdevelopment.com/davisisms/?p=82&preview=true&preview_id=82&preview_nonce=32c77db2e4