# MVC application, set session variables then open asp.net popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, popup

I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve the following.

Within an MVC application - 
Have a link which queries a database for some values, sets those values as session variables and then opens a pop-up window(which is an asp.net webform within the MVC app)

It's basically to allow us to run Crystal Reports, the link would set the Report ID in a session variable which would then be accessible in the asp.net webform.
My confusion is the setting of the session variable on click of the link and then opening the popup.
Can it be done and if so any links or pointers?

Edit:
Javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function flagInappropriate(postId) {

       var url = "/Home/FlagAsInappropriate/" + postId;

       $.post(url, function(data) {
       if (data) {
           alert("True")

           } else {
               // callback to show error/permission
           }
       });
   }
```

Controller

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public bool FlagAsInappropriate(int id)
        {
            // check permission
            bool allow = true;

            // if allow then flag post
            if (allow)
            {
                // flag post

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }





        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, yes. I've achieved something similar for the purposes of generating reports (predominantly so the report URL is hidden from the user and so some tracking and authentication could be achieved using once-off tokens). My solution was as follows:

1. Perform an AJAX call to a Web Method in your application to set the relevant session variable(s).
2. Return a value from the Web Method to indicate whether it was successful.
3. For the "success" event handler of the AJAX call, open your relevant ASPX page to generate the report.

Simple as that. :)

Here's some sample code to attach the click event and do the AJAX call, based on your amended question:

```
<a href="#" id="ajaxTest-1" class="flag">Click to test AJAX call</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".flag").click(function () {
            flagInappropriate($(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]);
        });
    });

    function flagInappropriate(postId) {
        var url = "/Home/FlagAsInappropriate/" + postId;

        alert(url);

        $.post(url, function (data) {
            if (data) {
                alert(data);

            } else {
                // callback to show error/permission
            }
        });
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into this further and found an example on here. I cant seem to get it to call the action method though.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764965/basic-ajax-example-with-asp-net-mvc/765974#765974

My controller is called Reports and when I use \Reports\FlagAsInappropriate  in my tests it does nothing. Am I missing something or using the wrong syntax?

Comment: OK, fist of all, what does the JavaScript / jQuery code look like that you are calling? And what does your controller look like? Have you tried debugging to see whether a breakpoint in the controller is actually reached when you make the AJAX call?

Comment: Hi, yes I have a breakpoint in the controller and it is not being reached. I even started a new blank project just to play around with this.
I've appended the code to the main post.

Comment: A bit of semantics, but remember the ";" after your alert... :) How are you attaching the click event handler to the anchor / button / element that is supposed to execute the AJAX call?

Comment: ; added after alert :)

This is the link that triggers the script
<a href="javascript:flagInappropriate(1)">Flag as inappropriate</a>

Comment: I added some sample code I used to test your scenario, which worked 100% for me...

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the code to your example and still no success. The breakpoint in the controller at public bool FlagAsInappropriate(int id) is never reached.
Do I need to do anything elsewhere? I'm on visual studio 2008 mvc 2, would that have any affect?

Comment: Is the URL alerted before the jQuery post happens, as in my example? What do you see when you put "alert($)" in? Are you sure jQuery is included in the page?

Comment: JQuery is included in the page - Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min-vsdoc.js

There is no alert at all when the link is clicked, when I add alert($), again nothing. :(

Comment: I stand corrected. I closed VS(clutching at straws) and now I receive 2 alerts.
1 - showing call to controller/method/id then
2 - "true" and a checkbox to prevent this page from creating additional dialogues

Comment: Yes! That's what you want... :D A more substantial test would be to make the Action return a string of sorts (instead o a bool) so you can see whether the POST Action is correctly called. So, now you're on your way to implement the reporting solution you need... Good luck!